# Unable change Swagger UI location path

Tags: symfony, swagger, symfony4, swagger-ui, api-platform.com

I made an api with api-platform.

I tried to edit the swagger_ui path **'/'** to **'/docs'** according to [api-platform documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#changing-the-location-of-swagger-ui) and allow **'/'** redirect to custom twig i made.

The swagger_ui documentation is available in **/docs** path but also still available in **'/'** path instead of my custom twig file.

Here is my config :

**app/config/packages/api_platform.yaml**

```
api_platform:
mapping:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    enable_swagger_ui: true
    enable_re_doc: true
    enable_docs: true
```

**app/config/routes/api_platform.yaml**

```
api_platform:
resource: .
type: api_platform
prefix: /
```

**app/config/route.yaml**

```
swagger_ui:
  path: /docs
  controller: api_platform.swagger.action.ui
hello-world:
  path: /
  controller: App\Controller\HelloController::index
```

Thanks by advance for your answer, if i haven't be clear, just le me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
api_platform:
mapping:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
enable_swagger_ui: true
enable_re_doc: true
enable_docs: true
```

with

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
    enable_swagger_ui: true
    enable_re_doc: true
    enable_docs: true
```

and pay attention to indentation in other files ...

Comment: It's actually the case, misunderstand with the stack overflow layout :/ I edit it

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be broken for now. There's a PR to fix the issue inside Api Platform but it hasn't been merged yet: https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/2749